# Is there anything in C# and Windows Forms that correspond to PostMessage?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window that show the result of multiple worker threads, but my worker threads should work with no interrupt(almost) so I want to post my notification data to the main window, I'm currently using `BeginInvoke` but it has a problem! I should call `EndInvoke` but where? I should create another thread just to service this? another option is using `PostMessage` directly but since I'm learning to work with `.NET` I prefer a `.NET` solution instead of a platform call(if available). So what should I do here to post something to main thread without blocking my worker threads?

Comment: Why do you need `EndInvoke`?  Are you expecting a return value?

Comment: Just a side note... Do your worker threads support cancellation or must their jobs always run to completion? I'm curious because so far as I know, to support cancellation the worker thread must block periodically to check a 'cancel' flag. That is, unless the check allows a race condition, which might be acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should simply use `BeginInvoke`, which is the direct equivalent of posting a message. You don't need to call `EndInvoke` at all unless you are interested in the return value.

If you *are* interested in the return value then the answer to "where do I cann `EndInvoke`" is kind of obvious: call it at the last moment before you need the return value in order to proceed.

Comment: Note that the reqirement for not needing to call `EndXXX` for a corresponding `BeginXXX` is a special case for [`BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx#remarksToggle). Anywhere else you MUST call the corresponding `EndXXX` unless the documentation says otherwise. For example from [Stream.BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx#remarksToggle) *"EndRead must be called once for every call to BeginRead. You can do this either by using the same code that called BeginRead or in a callback passed to BeginRead."*